# GLM rotation matrix differs from expected result

Tags: opengl, 3d, rotation, glm-math

I am trying to create a rotation matrix around the X-axis using glm::gtc::matrix_transform::rotate:

```
glm::rotate(glm::mat4f(1.0f), glm::radians(90.f), glm::vec3f(1.f, 0.f, 0.f));
```

I expected the resulting matrix to be (translational offsets removed):

```
1,       0,        0
0, cos(90), -sin(90)
0, sin(90),  cos(90)
0,       0,        0
```

(See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations)

However, the result is slightly off, i.e.:

```
1,         0,          0
0, 0.9996240, -0.0274121
0, 0.0274121,  0.9996240
0,         0,          0
```

I looked at https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/gtc/matrix_transform.inl and surely enough, the implementation uses a weird factor c + (1 - c) that would explain the results.

My question is now, why? Why is the definition of glm's rotation matrix different? What is the theory behind it?

Comment: glm doesn't use a "weird factor", it uses the well-known formula for rotations around an arbitrary axis (which will simplyfy to the basis rotations when that particular axis is selected). Note that the general formula is given in the same wikipedia article you already linked. It is totally unclear what you are doing, I can't reproduce this effect with glm.

Answer (score 0):

glm implementation uses [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle) formula from Wikipedia.
The following lines of code are identical to the formula:

```
Result[0][0] = c + (1 - c)      * axis.x     * axis.x;
Result[0][1] = (1 - c) * axis.x * axis.y + s * axis.z;
Result[0][2] = (1 - c) * axis.x * axis.z - s * axis.y;
Result[0][3] = 0;

Result[1][0] = (1 - c) * axis.y * axis.x - s * axis.z;
Result[1][1] = c + (1 - c) * axis.y * axis.y;
Result[1][2] = (1 - c) * axis.y * axis.z + s * axis.x;
Result[1][3] = 0;

Result[2][0] = (1 - c) * axis.z * axis.x + s * axis.y;
Result[2][1] = (1 - c) * axis.z * axis.y - s * axis.x;
Result[2][2] = c + (1 - c) * axis.z * axis.z;
Result[2][3] = 0;
```

There is nothing weird in `c + (1 - c)` because `c + (1 - c) * axis.x * axis.x` is the same as `c + ((1 - c) * axis.x * axis.x)`. Do not forget about operator precedence.

Most likely you are having issues with floating-point precision loss.